# Magento showing default images after moving to a new server

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a magento store with version 1.9 hosted on http://bandsawblades.co.uk

which I move to 1and1 server on a subdomain called

http://test.bandsawbladedirect.co.uk

The images are not showing on the home page on the new server but the images are there in the media folder. For example if you take the following featured product

http://test.bandsawbladedirect.co.uk/index.php/featured-products/mps-3742-bi-metal-air-saw-blade-with-1-2-mm-cutting-depth-and-ober-pneutec-chikago-pneumatic-shank.html

The images are there at

http://test.bandsawbladedirect.co.uk/media/product/7c6/morse-hef-band-saw-blades-1385-mm-54-1-2-long-various-widths-and-tpi-morse-hef-band-saw-blades-1385-mm-54-1-2-long-a4a.jpg

Which I derived from this page

http://bandsawblades.co.uk/index.php/featured-products/mps-3742-bi-metal-air-saw-blade-with-1-2-mm-cutting-depth-and-ober-pneutec-chikago-pneumatic-shank.html

I have set the media folder permission to 777, cleared var folder and set the permission to 777 there too but no luck. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have given `recursive` permission to all subfolders under media folder. Flushed `Magento Cache as well as Flushing Catalog Images Cache in System>Cache Management`. Also try to increase `memory_limit` parameter in your `php.ini` file .